# How does MediaWiki compose the image paths?

Tags: php, perl, mediawiki

I have a Perl application that parses MediaWiki SQL tables and displays data from multiple wiki pages. I need to be able to re-create the absolute image path to display the images, eg: `.../f/fc/Herbs.jpg/300px-Herbs.jpg`

From MediaWiki Manual:

> Image_Authorisation: "the [image] path can be calculated easily from the file name and..."

How is the path calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be to calculate the MD5 signature of the file (or the file ID in a database), and then build/find the path based on that.

For example, say we get an MD5 signature like "1ff8a7b5dc7a7d1f0ed65aaa29c04b1e"

The path might look like "/1f/f" or "/1f/ff/8a"

The reason is that you don't want to have all the files in 1 folder, and you want to have the ability to "partition" them across different servers, or a SAN or whatever in an equally-spread-out way.

The MD5 signature is a string of 16 "hex" characters.  So our example of "/1f/ff/8a" gives us 256*256*256 folders to store the files in.  That ought to be enough for anybody :)

---

Update, due to popular demand:

**NOTE** - I just realized we are talking specifically about how MediaWiki does it.  This is **not** now MediaWiki does it, but another way in which it **could have been done**.

By "MD5 signature" I mean doing something like this (code examples in Perl):

```
use Digest::MD5 'md5_hex';
my $sig = md5_hex( $file->id );
```

$sig is now 32 alpha-numeric characters long: "1ff8a7b5dc7a7d1f0ed65aaa29c04b1e"

Then build a folder structure like this:

```
my $path = '/usr/local/media';
map { mkdir($path, 0666); $path .= "/$_" } $sig =~ m/^(..)(..)(..)/;
open my $ofh, '>', "$path/$sig"
  or die "Cannot open '$path/$sig' for writing: $!";
print $ofh "File contents";
close($ofh);
```

Folder structure looks like

```
/
  usr/
    local/
      media/
        1f/
          f8/
            a7/
              1ff8a7b5dc7a7d1f0ed65aaa29c04b1e
```

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is incorrect:

- The MD5 sum of a string is 32 hex characters (128 bits), not 16
- The file path is calculated from the MD5 sum of the filename, not the contents of the file itself
- The first directory in the path is the first character, and the second directory is the first and second characters. The directory path is not a combination of the first 3 or 6 characters.

The MD5 sum of 'Herbs.jpg' is fceaa5e7250d5036ad8cede5ce7d32d6. The first 2 characters are 'fc', giving the file path f/fc/, which is what is given in the example.

Comment: I had been racking my brains for the actual server path for 3 days now! Thanks man :)

Answer (score 4):

In PHP you can call the following function to get the URL.  You may want to look at the php code to figure out how they calculate the path.

```
$url = wfFindFile(Title::makeTitle(NS_IMAGE, $fileName))->getURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small Bash script called *reorder.sh* which moves files from inside "images" to the specific sub folders:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /opt/mediawiki/mediawiki-cur/images

for i in `find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name .htaccess ! -name README ! -name reorder.sh -printf '%f\n'`; do
    path1=$(echo -n $i | md5sum | head -c1)    &&
    path2=$(echo -n $i | md5sum | head -c2)    &&
    mkdir -p $path1/$path2/                    &&
    mv $i $path1/$path2/;
done
```